# How to fix an Out Of memory when importing a large JSON file

Tags: java, json

I want to import a JSON file with 5 GB size but it shows me an `Out of memory` error. 
I set up the JVM by putting `-Xmx7700m -Xms7700m -XX: + UseConcMarkSweepGC` knowing that I have 8 GB of RAM in my computer but the program execution takes 45 minutes and then shows me this error:
i'm using maven depedency "com.googlecode.json-simple" version : 1.1.1

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit  exceeded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space //if i put
>   -Xmx5000m -Xms5000m

and this is the code of importing of the JSON File

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("url.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

can i find another solution to divide the JSON File into parts and import it part by part?

Comment: Don't you think that it matters **what** JSON parser you are using?! In other words: please tell us which library/tool you are using, and in which version that is.

Comment: it is a bad design to try to load a 5GB file into memory. you should look into a parser the supports streaming api .

Comment: Beyond that, you should look into your requirements. Do you really **want** all these 5 GB of JSON to be in memory at the same time, or wouldnt it be much better to parse/process/transform... that data in "smaller" junks? And for the record: a single JSON file with 5 GB ... that sounds weird.

Comment: If you have 8G you can't use 7.7G for the heap. Most likely the computer is swapping. Plus you may need more than 7G to keep a 5G file in memory when it has been parsed anyway. You need to use a streaming solution or you will need to get more RAM!

Comment: @GhostCat i put it into the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON file is a big array of JSON objects, can this assist you?:

```
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
...


  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(theFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  jsonReader.beginArray();
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
  while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
       JSONObject currentJsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JSONObject.class);
        // do stuff
   }
   jsonReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a mapper model class according with your JSON file fields. I gave an example.   
public class JsonToJavaObject {

    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name; 

   // Getter/Setter
}

// Create file from your JSON
File file = new File("url.json"); // Make sure your file name and location

// Make an input stream for the file's data
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(buf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Read stream of data
try (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(inputStreamReader)) {
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
     // Create JSON object
     JsonToJavaObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JsonToJavaOnline.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.getMessage();
}
```